# Laravel How To Do?

Tags: php, laravel

**Session class**

```
class Session extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function topics() {
        return $this->hasOne('Topic');
    }
}
```

**Topic class**

```
class Topic extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'topics';
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function sessions(){
        $this->belongsTo('Session');
    }

    public function questions(){
        $this->hasMany('Question');
    }
}
```

**Question class**

```
class Question extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'questions';
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function topic(){
        $this->belongsTo('Topic');
    }
}
```

From `Session::with('topics')->all();`, how to get output like this:

```
sessions:[{
     "id": 1
     "topics": {
         "id": 1,
         "questions": [
               {"id": 1},
               {"id": 2}
         ]
     }
}]
```

So, how can I get the question of the topic?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking, could you elaborate?

Comment: Question model should have a function name `topics` -> plural

Comment: If you want to eager load the nested `questions` relationship use the dot syntax: `Session::with('topics.questions')->get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do with re-reading the documentation some. There’s a few inconsistencies in your models—belongs to and has one methods should be named singularly (as there’s only one related model). Has many should be named plurally, as they can (potentially) have more than one related model.

In reading the [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#eager-loading) section on the Laravel docs site, you will note that you can eager-load even nested relationships. In your case, you could do:

```
Session::with('topics', 'topics.questions')->get();
```

You can then access the question like:

```
$sessions = Session::with('topics', 'topics.questions')->get();

foreach ($sessions as $session)
{
    $questions = $session->topic->questions;
}
```

Comment: A few notes... First, while following conventions with naming your relationship can help it is not mandatory. A relationship can have any name as long it doesn't conflict with any attributes (and doesn't contain `_`). Also when eager loading nested relations you don't need to specify the first relation twice. This is totally sufficient: `Session::with('topics.questions')`. Last but not least, you have to call `->get()` and not `all()`. `all()` will create a new query without the eager loading.

Comment: I like to be explicit with my eager loading, and also prefer to name relations per conventions as it reduces how much I have to “think” when reading code. Why name something plurally if I’m only every going to get one model, or vice versa?

Comment: As do I, but how you said it it could sound to others like the relationship has to have a certain name to work correctly. Which is not the case. I don't really see the benefit of having `with('topics', 'topics.questions')` but that's totally your choice...

Comment: I said “should be”, not “have to be”.